# new git user using netbeans support with REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD error

Tags: git, netbeans

I am a new GIT user, using the built in NetBeans support on win7. I have made some changes to my project files. When I try to push them to the remote server, I am getting the following year.

```
git push git@bitbucket.org:******/**.git +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Remote Repository Updates
Branch : master
Old Id : f2f9c7d23813d4ccc838d9aa0abd4875*******
New Id : 9277c9b01cf8d1aaff23003ce771cf*******
Result : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

 Local Repository Updates
 Branch : origin/master
 Old Id : f2f9c7d23813d4ccc838d9aa0abd4875******
 New Id : 9277c9b01cf8d1aaff23003ce771cf*******
 Result : NOT_ATTEMPTED

 ==[IDE]== Nov 13, 2012 1:14:35 PM Pushing finished.
```

Could someone explain what is going on, I'm not sure what to do next.

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is telling you that there have been updates to the remote repository since you last synchronized against it.  You need to pull those changes to your local system (using whatever the Netbean equivalent of `git pull` is) and integrate them into your local repository, then you'll be able to push to the remote repository.

This is what the `git push` on the command line says in this case:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'remote.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And the relevant portion of the man page says:

> NOTE ABOUT FAST-FORWARDS
>
> ```
>    When an update changes a branch (or more in general, a ref) that used
>    to point at commit A to point at another commit B, it is called a
>    fast-forward update if and only if B is a descendant of A.
>
>    In a fast-forward update from A to B, the set of commits that the
>    original commit A built on top of is a subset of the commits the new
>    commit B builds on top of. Hence, it does not lose any history.
> ```

Comment: Thanks - You fixed it, but how do you know this from the output?

Comment: Honestly, that is terrible output and whoever is repsonsible for it should be taken out and...vigorously chastised.  *I* know it from the output because "fast-forward merging" is what Git does when your changes are a linear series of changes on top of the old HEAD.  This is common git terminology, but your IDE should really be providing a more human readable answer.  The output from the `git` command line tools is substantially more helpful in this case.